# Expose Rest and Soap for one endpoint simultaneously by Spring and CXF

Tags: java, spring, rest, soap, cxf

I have a very simple service which has to be exposed as two way: REST and SOAP
I wrote following code:

```
@WebService(name = "Base")
@Path("/Base")
@Produces("application/json")
public class BaseService
{
    @POST
    @Path("/Hello")
    public String sayHello()
    {
        return  "Hello";
    }
}
```

That was my endpoint and I configure it as follows:

```
import org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBus;
import org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Server;
import org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSServerFactoryBean;
import org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsServerFactoryBean;
import org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.DependsOn;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import java.util.ArrayList;

@Configuration
public class CxfConfiguration {
    @Bean( destroyMethod = "shutdown" )
    public SpringBus cxf() {
        return new SpringBus();
    }

    @Bean @DependsOn( "cxf" )
    public Server getServer() 
    {
        JaxWsServerFactoryBean wsFactory = new JaxWsServerFactoryBean();
        wsFactory.setServiceBean(getBaseService());
        return wsFactory.create();
    }

    @Bean(name = "RestWS") @DependsOn( "cxf" )
    public Server getServerRest()
    {
        JAXRSServerFactoryBean restFactory = new JAXRSServerFactoryBean();
        ArrayList<Object> objectArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        restFactory.setServiceBean(getBaseService());
        restFactory.setProvider(new JacksonJsonProvider());

        return restFactory.create();
    }

    ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("facade.xml");

    @Bean
    public BaseService getBaseService()
    {
        return (BaseService)applicationContext.getBean("base_service");
    }
}
```

and finally `facade.xml` is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="base_service" class="BaseService"/>

</beans>
```

When I run my applicatiopn I get   `NullPointerException` :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'RestWS' defined in CxfConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Server]: Factory method 'getServerRest' threw exception; nested exception is org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:583)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1249)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1098)
```

The bottom line is that I would like to have both forms of service together and simultaneously but I get the above exception. When I comment one of the `getServer` or `getServerRest` method, everything will be OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to represent a service in both of **SOAP** and **REST** standard you have to define a server for **REST** and an endpoint for **SOAP**.
For your question, you have to change `CxfConfiguration`  class by the following code:

```
import org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBus;
import org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Server;
import org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSServerFactoryBean;
import org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsServerFactoryBean;
import org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.DependsOn;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import java.util.ArrayList;

@Configuration
public class CxfConfiguration 
{
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Bean( destroyMethod = "shutdown" )
    public SpringBus cxf() {
        return new SpringBus();
    }

    @Bean(name = "RestWS") 
    public Server getServerRest()
    {
        JAXRSServerFactoryBean restFactory = new JAXRSServerFactoryBean();
        ArrayList<Object> objectArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        restFactory.setServiceBean(getBaseService());
        restFactory.setProvider(new JacksonJsonProvider());

        return restFactory.create();
    }
   @Bean 
    public Server getServer() 
    {
        Bus bus = (Bus) applicationContext.getBean(Bus.DEFAULT_BUS_ID);
        Object implementor = getBaseService();
        EndpointImpl endpoint = new EndpointImpl(bus, implementor);
        endpoint.publish("/Base");
        return endpoint ;
    }

    ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("facade.xml");

    @Bean
    public BaseService getBaseService()
    {
        return (BaseService)applicationContext.getBean("base_service");
    }
}
```

That can solve your problem but I believe that it's better you have a difference paths or addresses for each **REST** and **SOAP** service.

Comment: Of course I edited some place, for example application context, because it was duplicated.